# Limit max connections on port iptables

Tags: linux, security, iptables

I want to know how to make a rule for limit the max IPs on certain port because I have a lot of flood with spoofed IPs and when the pool of IPs of my system reaches the limit the system collapses.

Comment: Eh so you want your system instead of being kind of DDOSsed at the Server-level to be DDOSsed at the kernel/ip-layer level?

Comment: yes this is the main problem